# Can two Bindable properties communicate with each other?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a control (deriving from `ContentView`) which has a `Frame` field:

```
public class SelectionFrame : ContentView
{
    Frame f1;
        public SelectionFrame()
        {
            f1 = new Frame
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                BackgroundColor = BorderColor,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Padding = new Thickness(0),
                CornerRadius = 7,
                HeightRequest = 14,
                WidthRequest = 14,
                Content = f2
            };
            Content = f1;
        }
```

I set its `BackgroundColor` through this `BindableProperty`:

```
   public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(SelectionFrame), defaultValue: Color.Black, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ColorChanged);

   public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
        }
```

then I use this control inside another custom control (`RadioButtonsGroup`), that has this `FrontColor` `BindableProperty`:

```
      public static readonly BindableProperty FrontColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FrontColor), typeof(Color), typeof(RadioButtonsGroup), defaultValue: Color.Black);

  public Color FrontColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(FrontColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FrontColorProperty, value); }
        }
```

And here I set the `BorderColor` of the `SelectionFrame` :

```
SelectionFrame circle = new SelectionFrame { ClassId = "r", BorderColor = FrontColor, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
```

I use the control like so:

```
<local:RadioButtonsGroup FrontColor="Red" x:Name="rbs"/>
```

but the `BackgroundColor` of the frame is not changed and still has the default color (Black).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't bound the `BackgroundColor` frame's property to your custom control property. You set it up on the constructor, bur you aren't listening for changes, what you are doing in this line:

```
SelectionFrame circle = new SelectionFrame { ClassId = "r", BorderColor = FrontColor, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
```

To correct it, just change your SelectionFrame constructor's code to this:

```
public SelectionFrame()
{
    f1 = new Frame
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        CornerRadius = 7,
        HeightRequest = 14,
        WidthRequest = 14,
        Content = f2
    };

    f1.SetBinding(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, new Binding(nameof(BorderColor)));
    f1.BindingContext = this;

    Content = f1;
}
```

Now you will be able to listen the changes to this property.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why: `f1.BindingContext = this`

Comment: 'Cause if you don't do that, the `Frame f1` will inherites the binding context of the `SelectionFrame` instance (or its parent binding context and so on). If you are wrapping views in your componente, you should be on charge of it's behavior.